# Can i set both current time and buffer limit on the same indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to show both current time (blue color) and buffer limit (gray color) on the same UIProgressView for my AVPlayer instance. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSAttributedStrings to accomplish this.

[Attributed Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here is an example...
Make a custom UIView that contains a UILabel and UIProgressView as subviews.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello. That is a test attributed string."];
[str addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:NSMakeRange(3,5)];
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(10,7)];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20.0] range:NSMakeRange(20, 10)];
label.attributedText = str;
```

And here is an example of a [custom UIProgressView implementation](http://iosameer.blogspot.com/2012/09/creating-custom-uiprogressview.html)

Comment: Can you post an example with UIProgressView in this case, please?

Comment: No, i need to show two indicators on the same UIProgressView, not the other colors or styles. Is it possible?

Comment: You should rephrase the question as what you are requesting is not clear. If you are trying to create 2 UIProgressViews then just add 2 to a UIView and display that.

Comment: I want to use something like progress bar on YouTube where red color means current location and gray color means loaded parts of the video

Comment: In that case just overlap the 2 progress views on one uiview so when the one on top becomes red it overlaps the other.

Comment: Do i need to set any additional properties in XCode for these progress views? Maybe clear color or smth like this?

Comment: Check out the class reference. Basically you will use a transparent area for the track that isnt filled in so the bottom progressView shines through. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html